# how do retrieve data from core data table ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, core-data

HI iam using core data in my test project.
Iam able to add contents from json to core data entity 'Book' .but when i tried to retriev e data am only getting last  one 'data' (total 37 data) ?
I created one mutablearray 'directors' to insert each retrieved values but that also not working.

Please check my code.

```
 NSError *error;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    directors=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"Book" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    for (NSManagedObject *info in fetchedObjects) {
        NSLog(@"1");
        [directors addObject:[info valueForKey:@"director"]];
        NSLog(@"Name: %@", info);

    }
    NSLog(@"%@",directors);
```

am printing '`NSLog(@"1");` to check how many times loop working ,but
and am getting output like this

```
2014-06-15 15:40:03.665 test[12489:1303] Name: <Book: 0x8c50580> (entity: Book; id: 0x8c66a60 <x-coredata://EEF91D97-C982-40E1-A898-9E646D206B39/Book/p1> ; data: <fault>)
2014-06-15 15:40:03.665 test[12489:1303] 1
2014-06-15 15:40:03.666 test[12489:1303] Name: <Book: 0x8c690d0> (entity: Book; id: 0x8c68420 <x-coredata://EEF91D97-C982-40E1-A898-9E646D206B39/Book/p2> ; data: <fault>)
2014-06-15 15:40:03.666 test[12489:1303] 1
2014-06-15 15:40:03.667 test[12489:1303] Name: <Book: 0x8f9c8d0> (entity: Book; id: 0x8d89870 <x-coredata://EEF91D97-C982-40E1-A898-9E646D206B39/Book/p3> ; data: {
    actors = "Hazel Crowney, Kiran Kumar, Shahbaaz Khan, Usha Bachani, Mohammed Iqbal Khan, Alka Verma";
    censor = U;
    director = "Arshad Yusuf Pathan";
    global = N;
    lang = Hindi;
    length = "";
    rating = 0;
    releasedate = "13th Jun 2014";
    synopsis = "The story of a racecar driver who loses his eyesight. While he suffers a setback, he learns about the true value of the relationships in his life. Through the course of the film, the hero realizes the";
    title = Unforgettable;
    trailer = "";
    type = MT;
    url = "http://cnt.in.bookmyshow.com/Events/Mobile/ET00022474.jpg?dtm=15614303";
})
```

current code
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see from the logs, all managed objects you've received from CoreData excepting last one are faulted. It means that these objects are instances of appropriate classes representing an entity (Book) but they are not initialized. They will be initialized automatically if you try to access some field of received record. 
I guess the following modification to your code should work:

```
for (Book *info in fetchedObjects) {
    NSLog(@"1");
    [directors addObject:info.director];
    NSLog(@"Name: %@", info);

}
NSLog(@"%@",directors);
```

Here `Book` is a class inherited from `NSManagedObject` that represents the entity named `Book`. You can generate this class for any entity by highlighting the entity in your CoreData model and selecting the <kbd>Create NSManagedObject subclass</kbd> item from the <kbd>Editor</kbd> menu.

More on faulting: [Core Data Programming Gudie](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFaultingUniquing.html)

Comment: Yes, you should create a Book class which is child of the NSManagedObject. Please do it using Xcode's auto-generator (Editor->Create NSManagedObject subclass)

Comment: Could you please post your updated code and logs output?

Comment: Thank you! It would be fine to take a look at your code filling CoreData with json data.

Comment: but then why its retrieving only one data?

Comment: The code for fetching data looks correct, so I'd like to check code that adds data to CoreData

Comment: I guess you should create `NSManagedObject*` (which is actually `Book*`) for each element in your JSON array. That is, place the `NSManagedObject *failedBankInfo = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Book" inManagedObjectContext:context];` inside the `for(int i=0;i<[[[data objectForKey:@"BookMyShow"] valueForKey:@"arrEvent"] count];i++)` loop.

Comment: can u write the same in pastebin,so i can understand the correct for mat

Comment: Here you are: http://pastebin.com/zAX7ZyhD. I mean that creation of the failedBankInfo should be inside the for loop (not before).

Comment: Fetch objects (`NSManagedObject*`, `Book*`) you'd like to delete then call the `deleteObject:` method for each object. Please take a look at the [Deleting Managed Object](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdCreateMOs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001654-SW1) section of the Core Data Programming Guide.